# plt.title not displaying

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy, title

I am unable to add `plt.title`

```py
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry.polygon import LinearRing
import pyproj

import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
from cartopy.mpl.ticker import (LongitudeFormatter, LatitudeFormatter)
import cartopy.io.img_tiles as cimgt

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

terrain = cimgt.Stamen('terrain-background')

extent = [18, 19, -33.5, -34.5]
lonmin, lonmax, latmin, latmax = extent

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11, 15), frameon=False)
plt.title('Real-Time GPS PPP test site locations',  fontsize=20)
plt.suptitle('Near-Side Perspective focused on Africa (right) \nwith red inset (left) Greater Cape Town, Western Cape', 
             y=0.70, fontsize=18)
ax = plt.subplot(1,2,1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(), frameon=False)#, frameon=False)

ax.set_extent(extent, crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.add_image(terrain, 9)

ax.set_xticks([18, 18.5, 19], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_yticks([-33.5, -34, -34.5], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
#add point
ax.plot(2057909.58, -4022282.12, color='purple', marker='o', markersize=2, 
        transform=ccrs.epsg(3857))
ax.plot(2075053.65, -4019595.49, color='purple', marker='o', markersize=2, 
        transform=ccrs.epsg(3857))
#add some text
ax.text(2056009.58, -4031002.12, 'Ctwn-SB', fontsize=12, horizontalalignment='left', 
        transform=ccrs.epsg(3857))
ax.text(2075053.65, -4015595.49, 'Cput01-TSM', fontsize=12, horizontalalignment='left', 
        transform=ccrs.epsg(3857))

ax2 = plt.subplot(1,2,2,projection=ccrs.NearsidePerspective(
    central_latitude=-15, central_longitude=19), frameon=False)
ax2.set_global()

ax2.add_image(terrain, 4)#, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())

gl = ax2.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), draw_labels=True,
                  linewidth=0.5, color='grey', alpha=0.2, linestyle='--')
gl.xlabels = False
gl.ylabels = False
gl.bottom_labels = False
gl.left_labels = False
gl.xformatter = LongitudeFormatter()
gl.yformatter = LatitudeFormatter()
gl.xlabel_style = {'size': 11, 'color': 'black'}
gl.ylabel_style = {'color': 'black'}#, 'weight': 'bold'}
ax2.plot(3148409.08, -3024295.70, color='purple', marker='o', markersize=2, 
         transform=ccrs.epsg(3857))
#add some text
ax2.text(29.7, -24.5, 'Pret-SB', fontsize=12, horizontalalignment='left', transform=ccrs.Geodetic())

nvert = 100
lons = np.r_[np.linspace(lonmin, lonmin, nvert),
             np.linspace(lonmin, lonmax, nvert),
             np.linspace(lonmax, lonmax, nvert)].tolist()
lats = np.r_[np.linspace(latmin, latmax, nvert),
             np.linspace(latmax, latmax, nvert),
             np.linspace(latmax, latmin, nvert)].tolist()

ring = LinearRing(list(zip(lons, lats)))
ax2.add_geometries([ring], ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                   facecolor='none', edgecolor='red', linewidth=0.75)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Why does the `plt.title` not display? How do I display the `title`?

Comment: where exactly are you wanting the "title" to appear? My guess is that you're actually wanting to pass ax.set_title()?

Comment: @JWB - A main title and sub title aligned at the top-centre. Is ax.set_title() for each axis / subplot (ax.) or a main (plt.) title?

Comment: @JWB - I ended up going with `ax.set_title('Real-Time GPS PPP test site locations', fontsize=24, x=1.1, y=1.1, pad=30)` and `ax2.set_title('Near-Side Perspective focused on Africa (right) \nwith red inset (left) greater Cape Town area, South Africa', fontsize=14, x=-0.1, y=0.96, pad=40)`. If you want to convert this suggestion to an answer; I will upgrade the "adds something useful" to an `Accept`.

Comment: @akriger went ahead and added it to the end, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that the [plt.title()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.title.html) method is for an `axes` object (one of your two graphs while the [plt.suptitle()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.suptitle.html) method is for the overall 'figure' object.

If you want a subtitle of sorts underneath the `plt.suptitle()` you'll need to either add a new line to the suptitle using `\n` within the string OR if you want the subtitle to have different font properties you can add `fig.text(x, y,'subtitle string', transform=fig.transFigure)` and play with the text formatting and positioning that way.

If you're fine with adding the title to the individual graphs you can use `ax.set_title('1st graph's title')` and `ax2.set_title('2nd graph's title')`. You'll use `ax` instead of `plt` since you set the axes objects explicitly!